# Use python to run a command line

Tags: python, command-line

I want to run a programme located in C, which can be run using command line using a line as follows

```
tclsh oommf.tcl avf2odt -average space -axis z -onefile  <filename>.txt  -headers none -ipat *.omf
```

This is the only thing I need to type in command line.

How can I run it using python?

Please be VERY relevant to the question. I have seen a lot of answers like: you can use 'subprocess' to realize it. However, none of them really solves the problem.

Comment: Please be very specific about what you have tried.

Comment: `subprocess` is very relevant to the question.

Comment: And please be very specific about how the answers to this question and  [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907698/how-to-run-a-tcl-script-in-a-folder-in-python) do not solve your problem. It seems you have left out quite a lot of detail.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your suggestions(and some critics)

To specify my problem, what I wish to achieve is using only python to run a command, as written in the code above, which can be run within command line. If this is still not specified enough, I shall list out all the procedure:
1 open command line
2 type in the line I wrote above
3 press Enter to execute
That's all

Now I want to achieve in Python.


I have searched an solution by myself, as below

import os
os.system("<whatever command to be executed>")

Comment: I am new to programming and that's why I need detailed explanation on 'subprocess', despite that I do know it can solve the problem. I even don't know what 'shell' is and you can imagine I may not be capable to describe the question in a skilled programmer's tone.

Comment: Have you tried using the methods proposed in the answers? Did they give you the results you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["tclsh", "oommf.tcl", "avf2odt", "-average", "space", "-axis", "z", "-onefile",  "<filename>.txt", "-headers", "none", "-ipat", "*.omf"])
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Comment: This is actually incorrect; you would pass **separate arguments** in the list, not one long string.

Comment: You're right; edited it.

Comment: All the more surprising your answer was marked as accepted before..

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (returns the process's printed output as a String)

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("tclsh oommf.tcl avf2odt -average space -axis z -onefile  <filename>.txt  -headers none -ipat *.omf", shell=True)
```

If you want the subprocess's return code instead (for example to check for 0 on success) use

```
import subprocess
return_code = subprocess.call("tclsh oommf.tcl avf2odt -average space -axis z -onefile  <filename>.txt  -headers none -ipat *.omf", shell=True)
```

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` where splitting up the arguments into a list of separate strings lets you avoid using the extra shell process altogether.